# iOS - How to flip title of UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

**Summary**

I'm doing an RTL of an app where as this current UI (https://gyazo.com/be662ea78ed090be366767bbb9fe0649) needs to be mirrored to be like this one (https://gyazo.com/f62d49409b3e682997921f8511f5c97c).

**Problem**

I can't flip the title in my UIButtons

**What I've tried**

(1) Flipping the UIView where my buttons are, just animate it using this code:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.numberPadGroup
                      duration:3.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:nil
                    completion:nil];
```

(2) Using this code just animate also my numberPadGroup:

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.numberPadGroup cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

How can I achieve flipping the titles in my buttons?

Comment: ForgotMyRealAccount I got the solution.Refer my below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to flip the button:

```
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
```

if you want to flip view container with some buttons:

```
myViewContainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
```

and the same with animation:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Flip" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't realized the answer is just in there.. I think i need to read more about this CGAffineTransform. Thanks Sir!

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this by below coding

```
- (IBAction)actionFlipButtonTitle:(id)sender
{

    [UIView transitionWithView:self.flipLabelButton duration:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animations:^{

    [self.flipLabelButton setTitle:@"Flipping" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class UIImage: ... {
    public func imageFlippedForRightToLeftLayoutDirection() -> UIImage
    public var flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection: Bool { get }
    ...
}
```

You should define your RTL language in project settings. UI should flip automatically, however some items might be needed to flip programmatically.

To test your RTL design you can edit scheme to preselect system language